# How to attach to a process from monodevelop inside flatpak

Tags: monodevelop, attach-to-process, flatpak

I installed MonoDevelop 6 via FlatPak (http://www.monodevelop.com/download/linux/). Now I'm trying to attach to a running process to be able to debug it. But all I can see in MonoDevelop under Run --> Attach to Process are four processes, I guess from inside the FlatPak sandbox.

How can I attach to a process with MonoDevelop running inside FlatPak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you can do nothing at this moment,

http://apebox.org/wordpress/linux/1184

The packager has documented many past and current issues related to the sandboxing and it might take extra time to fix.